# What is this strange flying fish creature?

Tags: outbreak-company

At the end of the opening sequence of Outbreak Company, the main characters can be seen riding some sort of huge flying fish creature. I've watched 11 episodes so far, and I didn't catch any sights of anything remotely similar, or even a mention of what it could be.

What is it? Does it have a name (either species or individual name)? Does it appear anywhere in the story at all (e.g. in later novels)?

[image]

Comment: I guess this is just a fun fantasy thing to do − let the characters ride unusual creatures in op/ed sequences.

Comment: Could this possibly be the Pet fish of Her highness "Elizabeth" that died after the maid got stabbed? Like a reincarnation? Honestly this is the only fish i saw in this anime.

Comment: I am sure it is just a fun fantasy element that the animators put in. Like you said it could of been covered in the other books but I doubt it has any significance other than it looks cool. It's not unusual to see thin ks in the opening and ending songs to an anime. They are made to look cool and maybe corresponding to the song.

Comment: It reminds me of Remoraid in Pokemon when I first saw it, but the appearance is not anywhere close, except for the skin color.

Comment: I have watched outbreak company many times and feel that the fish was just another element to add to the beauty of the whole fantasy element of the show.

Comment: That is just an Add-on to act as another feel for this fantasy world or just..letting the viewers realized that is the only scene you can see them all of them are happy together

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I know of to this creature, is the [mythological *Peng*, a fish-bird hybrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peng_(mythology)) from ancient Chinese folklore. Technically, it is either a bird that can transform into a fish, or vice versa.

I am not aware of any explanations in the anime or in the light novels for this creature, but I suggest that it was included to add to the fantastical atmosphere of the anime, add another magical creature to the repetoire, as well as being something fun and exciting for the viewers to watch during the credit sequences!

Nevertheless, the Peng is an appropriate creature to use as a model, since its flight was associated with being uplifted by 'righteousness' and 'virtue', and for a long time stood as a metaphor for 'broadening one's mind' or 'expanding one's horizons'. This is a very apt theme for *Outbreak Company*, which is all about 'breaking' through to the other side, and expanding into new ground, both physically and mentally. Both Kano and Myucel must grow and broaden their minds and experiences, and so the Peng is an excellent metaphor for them!